# Error running the node module 'run-headless-chromium' on Mac

Tags: protractor, node-modules, xvfb

I have installed run-headless-chromium but when i use the command './run-headless-chromium.js protractor.conf.js I get the error:

```
Xvfb not found. Please install xvfb before trying again.
```

I have run the command npm install xvfb and can see it in my node modules, so I don't know why this is popping up. Does anyone have any suggestions? It says on the xvfb page that it is for linux and Mac, and I am on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Running headless Chromium with `xvfb` is an old and resource inefficient method. I recommend you to take a look at: https://github.com/dtolstyi/node-chromium